# Azure DevOps Server 2019 - How to select multiple builds

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

In TFS 2018 we were able to select multiple builds in the build results page. 
After we upgraded to 2019, it seems we can no longer multi-select completed builds and perform an action on these, such as removing builds.

Can this still be done, or should this now be done using the API ? which would of course not be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to select multiple builds

I'm afraid this feature can not be done in azure devops 2019 now, also there's no directly api can let you get the feature e.g batch delete.

In fact, in TFS 2018, when you multi-select the builds and delete them, you could see the detailed progress from `F12`:

[image]

Actually, it executes the `delete` api in a **loop** to achieve the effect of a `batch delete`.

---

So, as a work around since there's no directly api to achieve such **batch** action, you can make use of `foreach` in powershell.

For example of `batch delete`,

```
DELETE https://{instance name}/{collection name}/{project name}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=5.0
```

You could make use the `for loop` with the powershell scripts into buildid(s) to delete them.

Simple delete script:

```
$url = https://{instance name}/{collection name}/{project name}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=5.0
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Delete -ContentType application/json
```

Comment: Thanks for the details, its really a petty that this feature has been removed.
In the UI you can easily toggle builds to the delete based on the information you see. Through powershell you need to define the correct filters and will just take more time. 
Will this feature be added back ?

Comment: @Nico. I could not guarantee this because I do not belong product team. This based on the impact of users. Our product team would consider them based on the priority of it. There has such feature suggestion in our forum: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/601108/select-multiple-builds-at-the-same-time.html. You can vote and comment it there to push its priority.